# PHPStorm как изменить горячие клавиши?

Tags: phpstorm

Как в *PHPStorm* сменить горячие клавиши?

Меня интересуют клавиши *debug*, в частности <kbd>F9</kbd> и <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Мне надо, чтобы было как в Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Открываете **Settings > Keymap** в поисковой строке **Keymap** вбиваете **debug**. Там и найдутся заданные комбинации, которые можно по правому клику изменить/дополнить.

Comment: спасибо. Для того же, чтобы получить схему сочетания клавиш как в Visual Studio - есть в PHPStorm уже готовая схема. Выбирается в списке Keymap.

Comment: О да, об этом то я совсем забыл! :)